# Get regions within black border of image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I begin with the following image:

[image: Initial image]

I perform local thresholding by comparing a pixel to its neighborhood mean. I also crop out the white border surrounding the image after this local thresholding with the following code:

```
I = imread('img_path');
N = 21;
localMean = conv2(double(I), double(1/(N^2) * ones(N)), 'same');
BW = I > localMean;
borderSize = ceil(double(N) / 2);
R = [borderSize, borderSize, size(BW, 2) - 2*borderSize, size(BW, 1) - 2*borderSize];
BW = imcrop(BW, R);
```

This leaves me with the following image:

[image: Segmented Cells]

As you can see, there is a clear black border surrounding each of the segmented cells. How do I go about removing all things in this image OTHER than those regions within the black border?

If this is not possible, then are there any other techniques I should take a look at that might make give my local thresholding less noise?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Otsu's thresholding ([`graythresh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html)) and morphological operations:

```
im = im2double(imread('cells.png'));
% otsu thresholding
t = graythresh(im);
bw = im > t;
% morphological open to remove small noise
bw = imopen(bw,strel('disk',5,0));
% fill holes to form solid objects
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');
% show
imshow(bw)
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh I had never seen `imopen`. I'll try it out.

Comment: it's the same as applying `imerode` and then `imdilate` with the same structuring element

Comment: Ugh right. We just learned about openings and closings in my CV course